# XPath regex combined with preg_match

Tags: regex, preg-match

I have a simple but invisible (for me) error in code. Can you help me?

With this code in my php file:

```
$location = $xpath2->query("//script")->item(1)->textContent;
```

I got (select) this:

```
<script class="" type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[                                   
var html = '';                             
var lat  = 44.793530904744074;                                        
var lang = 20.5364727973938;                              

if (GBrowserIsCompatible())
{
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    var ct = new GLatLng(lat, lang);
    map.setCenter(ct, 15);
    map.addControl( new GSmallMapControl() );
    //map.addControl( new GHierarchicalMapTypeControl () );
    var gm=new GMarker(ct);
    if(html != '') {
        GEvent.addListener(gm, "click", function() {
            this.openInfoWindowHtml( html );
        });
    }
    map.addOverlay(gm);
    map.enableContinuousZoom();
    map.enableInfoWindow();
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Then I try to fetch 'lat' and 'lang' with this code:

```
$location = $xpath2->query("//script")->item(1)->textContent; 

preg_match('/var\s+lat\s+=\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s*;/', $location, $lat); 
preg_match('/var\s+lang\s+=\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s*;/', $location, $lng); 
$data['lat'] = $lat[1]; 
$data['lng'] = $lng[1];
```

But always show that `lat` and `lang` is `0`, `0` when they should be `44.34534` and `20.5345`.

PLEASE HELP! where you think that I'm wrong (my English is not very well, sorry for that)

Comment: Are you sure `lang` is spelled correctly?

Comment: yes i'm sure becouse i copy that code. 100% is 'lang'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like below. Beware though you're trying to parse JavaScript.

preg_match(`'/(?:^|(?<=\s))var\s+lat \s* = \s* (?=[^;]*\d) ([+-]?\d*\.?\d*)\s*; /x'`, $location, $lat);
preg_match(`'/(?:^|(?<=\s))var\s+lang\s* = \s* (?=[^;]*\d) ([+-]?\d*\.?\d*)\s*; /x'`, $location, $lng);

Run sample: http://www.ideone.com/SEgVb

Or, just try to get more general information:

preg_match(`'/(?:^|(?<=\s))var\s+lat \s*=\s* ([^;]*) \s*; /x'`,  ...

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
preg_match('/var\s+lat\s+=\s+([\d.-]+)/', $location, $lat); 
preg_match('/var\s+lang\s+=\s+([\d.-]+)/', $location, $lng);
```

The [\d.-]+ matches any group with numbers . or - (lat/lon can be negative)